# please help to parse json

Tags: php, json

JSON:

```
    {
    "hashrate": 551125275,
    "miners": {
        "0x0916c53bc9c5a934f9b3dc1b01abd56241569977": {
            "lastBeat": 1538180874,
            "hr": 139778683,
            "offline": false
        },
        "0x3382e1265913d1f8161ead5422b7ca1e7cd80fc6": {
            "lastBeat": 1538180856,
            "hr": 22072348,
            "offline": false
        }
    },
    "minersTotal": 2,
    "now": 1538180878485
}
```

I want to get like this:
Account1:0x0916c53bc9c5a934f9b3dc1b01abd56241569977
Account2:0x3382e1265913d1f8161ead5422b7ca1e7cd80fc6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = ' {
    "hashrate": 551125275,
    "miners": {
        "0x0916c53bc9c5a934f9b3dc1b01abd56241569977": {
            "lastBeat": 1538180874,
            "hr": 139778683,
            "offline": false
        },
        "0x3382e1265913d1f8161ead5422b7ca1e7cd80fc6": {
            "lastBeat": 1538180856,
            "hr": 22072348,
            "offline": false
        }
    },
    "minersTotal": 2,
    "now": 1538180878485
}';

$data = json_decode($json);
$i = 1;
foreach ($data->miners as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Account' . $i++ . ':' . $key . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to work with JSON in PHP is using the JSON extension. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

So you can convert a JSON string to *stdClass* and vice-versa.

Like this:

```
$json_object = json_decode($json_string);
var_dump($json_object->miners);
```